# Can I use C# to write a Bluetooth PC client with Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a Bluetooth PC client that can do some simple interactive behavior with a Android device over Bluetooth. Then I learned that it is possible to use Windows Socket programming to achieve, however, when I'm trying to create a new socket, this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362910(v=vs.85).aspx) tells me to use AF_BTH as the address parameter, which is in a C++ struct as clarified in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362897(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here are my codes with errors:

```
Socket tempSocket = new Socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
```

So here is my question: Does it mean that I have to use C++ to achieve this? If not, how do I create a new Bluetooth-typed socket under C#?

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://32feet.codeplex.com/ for bluetooth connection
here is simple demo for discovering new devices:

```
List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] array = bc.DiscoverDevices();
int count = array.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Device device = new Device(array[i]);
    devices.Add(device);
}
```

refrence : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/06/21/working-with-bluetooth-devices-using-c-part-1/

32feet documentation  is good enough to look at (samples are in vb language but its .net - easy to convert to c#)